# Insert '20-001' into SQL Server database results in an error

Tags: .net, sql-server

I found an error while developing in .NET. I face a problem using a stored procedure. I set variable `@A` like this:

```
@A NVARCHAR(50) = ""
```

After .NET database connect and send to '20-001'

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", test.a);
```

But I get an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '22 001' to data type int.

My code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult test([FromBody]test test)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source());
         conn.Open();

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[test].[test]", conn);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FLAG", test.test);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQTYPE", "test_INSERT");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", test.a);

         using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while(reader.Read())
             { 
                 result = (int)reader[0];
             }

             reader.Close();
         }
    }

    if (result != 0)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
@a NVARCHAR(50) = ''
INSERT INTO test(a) VALUES (@a)
```

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: And show the complete application code you use to execute your sql statement.

Comment: then what method should i use instead?

Comment: Use the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method. An explicit initializer can handle more challenging cases, e.g. `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Filename", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 256, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput, Value = "Foo.bar" } );`.

Comment: The article linked to explains how to add them properly.

Comment: Also, since you're executing a stored procedure that does an `INSERT` and thus does not return a result set back, you should really use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`  instead of `ExecuteReader` ....

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '22 001' to data type int

is because of

1. type mismatch between stored procedure parameter and value passed in, or
2. type mismatch between value passed into insert statement and table datatype

Comments:

1. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` accepts all data types, then your code is OK here
2. In your stored procedure, you must define input parameter `@test as nvarchar(50)`
3. In the destination table `test`, the column `a` must be `nvarchar(50)` data type

Like this

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
(
     a nvarchar(50)
)
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [test].[test] 
    (@FLAG nvarchar(200),
     @REQTYPE nvarchar(200),
     @test nvarchar(50))
AS
    INSERT INTO test_table (a) 
    VALUES (@test)
GO
```